# What's the difference between these two statements in a Chef script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am using Chef to install packages. I am getting an error on line

```
node.default["installed_pkgs"] << 'amanda'
```

```
Undefined node attribute or method `<<' on `node'. To set an attribute, use `<<=value' instead.
```

If I change it to:

```
node.default["installed_pkgs"] = 'amanda'
```

it seems to work, or at least it doesn't error out. I took this over from someone that quit so I'm not sure of his code since I don't know Chef or Ruby that much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef: Undefined node attribute or method \`<<' on \`node' when trying to add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878933/chef-undefined-node-attribute-or-method-on-node-when-trying-to-add)

Answer (score 2):

your problem comes from her:
https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/d8172e646d9fbf43e57bca5e20d0ac352ba9a66a/lib/chef/node/attribute_collections.rb#L175

node does not know about << and thinks it's an attribute.

use

```
node.default["installed_pkgs"] = 'amanda'
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the attribute_collections.rb file. That's a very good reference

Comment: yeah. the advantage of ruby / interpreted languages is that you can look at the code pretty easily :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in Ruby.

`<<` is [shorthand for appending to the end to an array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).  If you have an array and you want to append to the end of it, then you would use `<<`.

`=` is vanilla assignment.  You use this to assign a value to a variable or hash, but you **have to be sure** that the value you're assigning is appropriate; if you assign a scalar value when Ruby expects an array, then your program will error out.