# in chef: Undefined node attribute or method `<<' on `node'

Tags: chef-infra

Another frustrating matter of works in testing not in prod.

The code is question appends a string to a node attribute.

```
if node['tom-ssh']['allow_groups']
  if !node['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'].include?("bots")
    node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] << "bots"
  end
else
    node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] = ["bots"]
end
```

This, as mentioned above works in test kitchen, in chef-shell in production, but running the recipe in prod throws the following:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
Undefined node attribute or method `<<' on `node'. To set an attribute, use `<<=value' instead.

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/tom-users/recipes/reboot_bot.rb:22:in `from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/run_context.rb:347:in `load_recipe'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/run_context.rb:303:in `block in include_recipe'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/run_context.rb:302:in `each'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/run_context.rb:302:in `include_recipe'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/tom-security-patches/recipes/default.rb:8:in `from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/run_context.rb:347:in `load_recipe'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/tom-users/recipes/reboot_bot.rb:

 15:      '/sbin/reboot'
 16:    ]
 17:  end
 18:  
 19:  # allow 'bots' to ssh log in
 20:  if node['tom-ssh']['allow_groups']
 21:    if !node['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'].include?("bots")
 22>>     node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] << "bots"
 23:    end
 24:  else
 25:      node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] = ["bots"]
 26:  end
 27:
```

The questions I found on the subject (for example [Chef: Undefined node attribute or method `<<' on `node' when trying to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878933/chef-undefined-node-attribute-or-method-on-node-when-trying-to-add)) refer to not using a priority on the `node` object, but I do, just a different one from that presented in the link.

I might be missing something stupid here, but it worked before, and still works in kitchen, so I ran out of places to look. Could it be some kind of strange compilation issue that does not replicate in `chef-zero`?

Comment: What version of Chef are you using?

Comment: latest (12.17.44). but I've tried downgrading to other versions and the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

what you probably need to do is :

node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] = DeepMerge.merge(node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'].to_hash,["bots"].to_hash )

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is more like this

```
node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] ||= []
node.normal['tom-ssh']['allow_groups'] |= %w{bots}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. `chef (12.17.44)> node.normal['blah']['boo'] |= %w{bots}
NoMethodError: Undefined node attribute or method `|' on `node'. To set an attribute, use `|=value' instead.`